# Slick.js Custom Paging hook and CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slick.js

I'm currently building a slider using Slick.JS alongside some SVG illustrations and I was wondering what the process would be to get the elements of the SVG to change fill colour when the relevant slide is active.

JS Fiddle below should show where I am at the moment:
http://jsfiddle.net/twqvchj6/5/

```
$('.tugslider').on('afterChange', function() {
      var dataId = $(this).slick('slickCurrentSlide');
      var slideno = $('a[data-slide]').data('slide');

      if(dataId == slideno + 1){

      }else{

      };

});
```

Currently I have a blank IF statement that I believe is the correct foundation, but I cannot figure out how to target each of the segment elements individually based on their data-slide number. I had a fill change in here previously changing CSS but it only changed the first segment.

Any help appreciated

Cheers!

Comment: I don't know if I understood correctly what you want to do, but if it's to retrieve the svg corresponding to the current slide, it would be enough to change the variable below:
`var slideno = $('a[data-slide="'+ dataId +'"]')`

Comment: Hey - thanks for this! Apologies if I was unclear in my initial post, I am trying to get the SVG fill colour to change in sync with the slide that is currently showing - so for example on the first slide the first segment would be red to indicate it's active.

I tried to implement your line of code here but I'm still uncertain of the actual process of taking that targeting into account for the if statement.

Comment: Man, i eddited your findle to change SVG color, follow the link: http://jsfiddle.net/twqvchj6/7/

If this solve your problem i will create a response to your answer.

Comment: This fixed it with some tweaking to get the slide numbers to match up correctly (Index returns as 0 for the first slide etc.) - here is the updated version http://jsfiddle.net/9czjekqv/3/

Thank you for your help! Much appreciated

Comment: Drchimpy Could you please mark this as solved by accepting my answer? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, only a few points should be adjusted:

1 - Using slick `afterChange` event inner declaration, you can receive the `currentSlide` param;

2 - You can use `$("[data-slide='" + dataId + "']")` to get the element referenced with index that you have (currentSlide), with this, create a control that manipulates your svg based on a class:

```
var dataId = currentSlide;
var svgs = $('a[data-slide]');
var slideno = $("[data-slide='" + dataId + "']");

svgs.find('.active').removeClass('active');
slideno.find('path').addClass('active');
```

3 - Slides index start in 0, update your HTML `data-slide`;

4 - Also, your HTML is not closing `</ul>` tag.

Final findle: http://jsfiddle.net/sparhawk_odin/u8vfgosp/